# Getting Attempted import error '../helpers/normalizeText' when compiling my react native app

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react native and while running my app I'm getting the following error:

```
/node_modules/react-native-elements/src/card/Card.js
Attempted import error: '../helpers/normalizeText' does not contain a default export (imported as 'normalize')
```

As a result my app does not start on Expo Client.

I have four files:

I am not importing normalizeText.js directly,

Here are my main files that are being used in the project

1. App.js

   ```
    import Main from './components/MainComponent';

    export default function App() {
      return (
        <Main />
      );
    }
   ```
2. MenuComponent.js

````
  import {View, FlatList} from 'react-native' ;
  import {ListItem} from 'react-native-elements';
  
  function Menu(props){
  
      const renderMenuItem = ({item, index}) => {
          return(
              <ListItem
                  Key={index}
                  title={item.name}
                  subtitle={item.description}
                  hideChevron={true}
                  leftAvatar={{ source: require('./images/uthappizza.png') }}
              />
          );
      }
      return (
          <FlatList 
              data = {props.dishes}
              renderItem={renderMenuItem} 
              KeyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
           
              
              />
  
      );
  }
  
  export default Menu; 

3) MainComponent.js 



```   import React, {Component} from 'react';
  import Menu from './MenuComponent';
  import {DISHES} from '../shared/dishes';
  
  class Main extends Component {
      constructor(props){
          super(props)
          this.state = {
              dishes : DISHES
          }
      }
      render(){
          <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
      }   
  }
  
  export default Main; ```

4) Dishes.js 

 This file is has a json objects list which is has information to populate the 
 app.
````

Comment: can you show us 1) the code you use to import whatever you want to import from `normalizeText.js`, and 2) the way you export things in that file?

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher, i'm not using **normalizeText.js** directly but I have included all the scripts i'm using in the original post. 

Thanks

Comment: hmm what version of `react-native-elements` are you using? It seems like an issue with that library, did you use `npm install react-native-elements`?

Answer (score 0):

Small Changes you need to add in the helpers `../helpers/normalizeText`.
Go to this path

```
node_modules/react-native-elements/src/helpers/noramlizeText.js
```

Change this line `module.exports = normalize;` to `export default normalize;`